# What events do I need when I scale a subclassed WPF Image control within a scrollviewer?

Tags: wpf, scaling, scrollviewer, resize

I have subclassed the image control (to display images at their true pixel size, regardless of resolution setting in metadata) and I want to implement scrolling and zooming, by using a ScaleTransform (within a LayoutTransform). This works fine at 100%, but when scaled the scrolling size stays at the size of the 100% image.

My XAML is:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="imgScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <PL:DpiAgnosticImage x:Name="Ctrl_ImgMain" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseWheel="Ctrl_ImgMain_MouseWheel" VerticalAlignment="Top"   >
         <Image.LayoutTransform>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ZoomLevel}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomLevel}">
              </ScaleTransform>
         </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </PL:DpiAgnosticImage>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The C# for my DpiAgnosticImage class is:

```
class DpiAgnosticImage : Image
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var bitmapImage = Source as BitmapImage;

        var desiredSize = bitmapImage == null
            ? base.MeasureOverride(constraint)
            : new Size(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);

        return desiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return new Size(Math.Round(DesiredSize.Width), Math.Round(DesiredSize.Height));
    }
}
```

I've searched around but the closest that I have found to this problem suggests using LayoutTransform - which I already am.
I suspect that I need to implement something to change the scrollviewer size when the image is scaled, but I am struggling to find out what is required. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derived image control works fine if you simply don't override `ArrangeOverride`.

Apparently the `DesiredSize` property gets the size calculated by `MeasureOverride` and subsequently transformed by `LayoutTransform`. This might by obvious during layout, although it doesn't seem to be well documented in the MSDN of [DesiredSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.desiredsize.aspx) and [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx).

Found this in Charles Petzold, "Applications=Code+Markup", p.831:

> The DesiredSize property of an element's child reflects the
>   LayoutTransform, ...

Anyway, if you need to override `ArrangeOverride` for any other reason, simply return the value of the `finalSize` argument.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what the problem was